# PHP Excel performance is slow

Tags: php, performance, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I want to generate an excel sheet which contain some default fields and variable number of comment fields and data related to comment. I want to set specific width and wrap text for comment fields.Righ now I am using this code

```
 $excelObj = new \PHPExcel();     
  $ews = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
  $ews->setTitle('SurveyDetails');

  $ews->fromArray($header, ' ', 'A1'); //Write the header from array
  $ews->fromArray($content_arr, ' ', 'A2'); // Write the content from array

  $header_style = array(
      'font' => array('bold' => true,),
      'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER, 'vertical' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER),
  );

  $content_style = array(
      'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER, 'vertical' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER),
  );

  $start_end_columns = $excelObj->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->calculateWorksheetDimension();
  preg_match_all('!\d+!', $start_end_columns, $matches);
  $numbers = implode(':', $matches[0]);
  $columns = explode(":", $numbers);
  $header_end_column_no = $columns[1];
  $header_start_end = str_replace($header_end_column_no, 1, $start_end_columns); // A1:G1

  $ews->getStyle($header_start_end)->applyFromArray($header_style);
  $start_end_columns = str_replace("A1", "A2", $start_end_columns); // Start column of content changed A1 to A2
  $ews->getStyle($start_end_columns)->applyFromArray($content_style);

  $cols = explode(":", $start_end_columns);
  $endColmn = $cols[1];
  $endColmn = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $endColmn);

  $activeSheetObj = $excelObj->getActiveSheet();

  //Set the autosize height for all the cells
  $activeSheetObj->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);

  $this->log(sprintf("Before set hyper link excel projectId : %s, surveyId : %s", $projectId, $survey_id), LogLevel::INFO);
  //Set the hyperlink in the path field
  $i = 2;
  $count = count($content_arr);
  foreach ($content_arr as $content) {
    $activeSheetObj->getCell('F' . $i)->getHyperlink()->setUrl($content['path']);
    $i++;
  }

  $activeSheetObj->getStyle('G'.'2:'.'G'.$count)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
  $this->log(sprintf("After setting hyper link projectId : %s, surveyId : %s", $projectId, $survey_id), LogLevel::INFO);
  //Set specific width for the note and comment fields
  $activeSheetObj->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(35);
  $l = 0;     

  if (strcmp('G', $endColmn) != 0) {
    for ($col = 'J'; $col != $endColmn; $col++) {
      if ($l % 3 == 0) {
        $activeSheetObj
                ->getColumnDimension($col)
                ->setWidth(35);
        $activeSheetObj->getStyle($col.'2:'.$col.$count)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
      }
      $l++;
    }

    $activeSheetObj->getColumnDimension($endColmn)->setWidth(35);
    $activeSheetObj->getStyle($endColmn.'2:'.$endColmn.$count)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true); 
  }
  unset($content_arr);
  $this->log(sprintf("After setting width projectId : %s, surveyId : %s", $projectId, $survey_id), LogLevel::INFO);


  $writer = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelObj, 'Excel2007');
  //Save to perticular location      
  $keyname = "videos/Export/" . $projectId . "/" . $fileName;
  $writer->save('/home/senchu/Documents/Infrass.xlsx');
```

But it takes about 3 seconds to complete the process on 10 columns and 400 rows. Is there any way to optimize this code so that to increase the performance. When I tried caching I didn't get much performance improvement.

Instead of iterating each row and setting hyper link like

```
$activeSheetObj->getCell('F' . $i)->getHyperlink()->setUrl($content['path']);
```

is there any method to set hyper link from array.so that we can avoid this much number of iterations.

Comment: Do you have to use excel files? If you could export the excel data to a text file (.csv maybe), I think parsing that would be a lot faster

Comment: First of all, they have moved to PHPSpreadsheet, so I would recommend using that instead. As for the code: I believe some of your code writing data is missing, but I am unable to fully verify that because the code is a giant collection of random things done in an excel file. If the structure makes sense, it does not make sense to me. You are logging some things. Have you already timed which part of this code performs bad?

Comment: @Sumurai8 mainly the from the  part "03:44:47 Info: Before set hyper link excel " to "03:44:47 Info: After setting width projectId " part it takes more time(1 sec).

Comment: @Sumurai8 and some time the performance also varies , bcz sometime it finish the task with in 1 sec to 2 sec

Comment: @KayakinKoder I need to use excel files(.xlsx)